# How to blur status bar on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, statusbar, blur

I want to apply blur effect all over the screen behind my alert dialog. I use `BackdropFilter` for that but the status bar on Android is still not blur. Is there any possibility to blur the status bar?

Here is how is looking my app:

[image]

Here is how I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: Try to add your code snippet

Comment: this is an open issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24969)

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes, thank you for pointed out that link!