# change status bar image in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to have a view like in image. But don't know how to blur status bar with the app screen.

I have tried this property of AppBar, but it didn't work:

```
systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.green, // <-- SEE HERE
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //<-- For Android SEE HERE (dark icons)
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light, //<-- For iOS SEE HERE (dark icons)
  )
```

Comment: I don't think there's a simple solution to that. I suggest you investigate related issues on stackoverflow and github: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73529684/how-to-blur-status-bar-on-flutter
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24969

They offer some potential workarounds

Answer (score 0):

From what i have found it has to be at the root entry point of the application. What i have below works for android, have not tried or verified on iOS

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        systemNavigationBarColor: theme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
);
```